# Why aren't my nested routes working? ReactRouter4

Tags: react-router-v4

I am using `react-router` `v4` for my app.  Here is my `routes.js`:

```
const routes = (
    <Route 
      path="/" 
      render={props => (
        <App>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/org/:slug" component={Org} />
            <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route exact path="*" component={Error.NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </App>

      )}
   />
);
```

All of the routes work fine.  In the `Org` component, I have another set of routes:

```
export default () => (
  <LookUp>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={LogIn} />
      <Route path="/create-account" component={CreateAccount} />
      <Route path="/request-password" component={Auth.Request} />
      <Route path="reset-password" component={Auth.Reset} />
    </Switch>
  </LookUp>
);
```

I am hitting the `render` function in the `LookUp` Component, which is very simple:

```
render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
}
```

I can put a breakpoint in the render function and see the `children`.  The `Switch` child is there and all 4 of the `Route` as the children of the `Switch`, but I don't route to any of the routes in the `Org` file.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. The second `<Switch>` in Org will render only if the address is starting `/org/`, otherwise it will not see these routes at all and therefore it cannot use them.

If you want to render the urls like /org/login, /org/create-account and so on, you have to use `{match.url}`

```js
<Route path={match.url + '/login'} component={LogIn} />
```

Or if you want to use /login, /create-account... without /org/ prefix, you cannot put these Routes inside `/org/:slug` Route